# Keeping gym gear separate from normal clothes

Tags: cleaning, clothing, shoes

I have one duffle bag which I use for the gym but the clothes get mixed up and sometimes smell. How can I make sure to keep the gym clothes/shoes separate from regular clothes in the same bag?

Answer (score 5):

Bag-ception. Semi-airtight bags, available from your local supermarket, can be used to store the smaller of the two bundles. A big zip-lock bag will do the same trick in a more user-friendly way.

Comment: (Cotton or Nylon laundry bags might do instead.)

Answer (score 1):

We have a few sets of the Bagail Bags - very useful for packing in all kinds of scenarios. They could probably help. I don't like the idea of putting gym close in air tight bags, as that will likely make them smell worse and keep them from drying.